# Nested Switch statement - returning to beginning of switch

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I am writing a piece of code to convert between Celsius and Fahrenheit using switch statements as you can see in the code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

float celsius;
float fahrenheit;

void convertF()
{
    celsius = ((fahrenheit - 32) * 5) / 9;
}

void convertC()
{
    fahrenheit = (((celsius * 9) / 5) + 32);
}

int main()
{
    unsigned short choice;

    cout << "Welcome to the temperature converter.\n";
    cout << "Please press '1' for celsius to fahrenheit conversion" << endl;
    cout << "Or, type '2' for fahrenheit to celsius conversion." << endl;
    cout << "To exit, press 0" << endl;
    cin >> choice;

    switch(choice) 
    {
        case 0:
          return 0;
          break;

        case 1:
          cout << "Please enter temperature in celsius:";

          cin >> celsius;
          convertC();

          cout << "\n";
          cout << "Computing...\n\n";
          cout << "The temperature in Fahrenheit is " << fahrenheit << ".\n";
          cout << "Press any key to terminate the program." << endl;
          cout << endl;
          break;

        case 2:
          cout << "Please enter temperature in fahrenheit:";

          cin >> fahrenheit;
          convertF();

          cout << "\n";
          cout << "Computing...\n\n";
          cout << "The temperature in celsius is " << celsius << ".\n";
          cout << "Press any key to terminate the program." << endl;
          cout << endl;
          break;    

        default:
          cout << "That is not an option!" << endl;
          cout << "Please close the program and try again." << endl;
          break;
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

If the user selects 1 or 2, the program performs the conversion. You then press any key to end the program.

However I would like to offer them the chance of another conversion after the first one, so they can exit the program or perform another conversion. I have tried to put another switch statement within case 1 and case 2 but it didn't work.

What is the best way to solve this? I am thinking if there is an alternative to using the switch statement completely?

Comment: What you need is a loop. A do..while loop to be precise

Comment: Would I not need the case statements at all then?

Comment: You'll need them once. Nesting is not required.

Comment: You could also put everything in a function, such that you just need to call this function to perform another conversion.

Comment: So I would say do{ then all my case statements} while case!=0 ( if we say 0 exits the program)
Tony, do I not already have two functions in ConvertC and convertF?

Comment: I meant only the part in main.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just change your code like this:

```
    cout << "Welcome to the temperature converter.\n";
    while(1)   // <----- Add this 
    {          // <----- Add this 
        cout << "Please press '1' for celsius to fahrenheit conversion" << endl;
        //...
        // All your code down to
        //...
       cout << "Please close the program and try again." << endl;
       break;
       }

    }  // <----- Add this 

return 0;
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked perfectly, however I am a little unsure as to what while(1) does, could you explain a little please? thanks

Comment: @Tony Hibbert: `while(1)` always evaluate `true`, so it loops endlessy, unless there is a `break` statement somewhere in the block

Comment: @Black Moses - Thanks, I understand that now. However if I press 0 to try and close the program it still loops back to the start. Do I just put the default case statement outside of the while?

Comment: @TonyHibbert - No keep the default inside the loop but maybe change the printed text a bit. However if you want the program to terminate you can add a `return 0` in the default case.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to enclose the part of the program with the switch statement in some kind of loop.

The program can look something like the following

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

float convertF( float fahrenheit )
{
    return ((fahrenheit - 32) * 5) / 9;
}

float convertC( float celsius )
{
    return (((celsius * 9) / 5) + 32);
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Welcome to the temperature converter.\n";

    while ( true )
    {
        cout << "\nPlease press '1' for celsius to fahrenheit conversion" << endl;
        cout << "Or, type '2' for fahrenheit to celsius conversion." << endl;
        cout << "To exit, press 0" << endl;

        unsigned short choice;

        if ( !( cin >> choice ) || ( choice == 0 ) ) break;

        switch( choice )
        {
            float celsius;
            float fahrenheit;

        case 1:
            cout << "Please enter temperature in celsius:";

            cin >> celsius;

            cout << "\n";
            cout << "Computing...\n\n";
            cout << "The temperature in Fahrenheit is " << convertC( celsius ) << ".\n";
            break;

        case 2:
            cout << "Please enter temperature in fahrenheit:";

            cin >> fahrenheit;

            cout << "\n";
            cout << "Computing...\n\n";
            cout << "The temperature in celsius is " << convertF( fahrenheit ) << ".\n";
            break;    

        default:
            cout << "That is not an option!" << endl;
            break;

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For more readability you could introduce an enumeration like

```
enum { CELSIUS = 1, FAHRENHEIT = 2 };
```

and use its enumerators as case labels. For example

```
switch( choice )
{
    float celsius;
    float fahrenheit;

case CELSIUS:
    //...

case FAHRENHEIT:
    //...

default:
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use switch statement within a loop:

```
do
{
    cin >> choice;
    switch(choice)
    {
        //cases
    }
}
while (choice != 0);
```

or

```
choice = /* not 0 */;
while(choice != 0)
{
    cin >> choice;
    switch(choice)
    {
    //cases
    }
}
```

or

```
for(unsigned int choice = /* not 0 */; choice != 0; )
{
    cin >> choice;
    switch(choice)
    {
        //cases
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a while loop like this:

```
unsigned int choice;
do
{
    cin >> choice;
    // switch with only case 1 and 2
}
while(choice != 0);
return 0;
```

I don't know what you mean by an alternative to using the switch statement completely.

Answer (score 0):

A `do-while` loop is probably the simplest way to solve it. You want to check `while(choice != 0)` to keep running the loop until the user enters 0 as a choice, which means you'll want to have the input section also within the `do-while` loop, as you want to get further input, and also have the switch statement within the `do-while`. When `choice` is entered as `0` the loop will then end.

This shows some examples of `do-while` loops: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/